# MultipleCollectionViews with two arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

At the moment I'm parsing data from a Json and saving it local. Then I fill up a CollectionView with the data from the first Array. But now I want to add a second CollectionView that depends on the selection from the first CollectionView.

My Json structure:

```
struct Posts: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let ImageURL: String
    let Rarity: [PostType]
}

struct PostType: Codable {
    let type: String
    let test: int
    let test2: String
}
```

What I tried:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == self.PostsCollectionView{
    return getPostsFromDisk().count
    }else
    {
        return feedWrapper.count //not working

    }

}
var feedWrapper:[PostType] = []

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == self.PostsCollectionView{
    let cell = PostsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PostsUICollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PostsUICollectionViewCell

    cell.PostsNameLbl.text = getPostsFromDisk()[indexPath.row].name
    cell.PostsImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: getPostsFromDisk()[indexPath.row].ImageURL))

        return cell
    }else
    {
        let cell = PostsRareCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PostsRareCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PostsRareCollectionViewCell

        if(feedWrapper[indexPath.row].type == "normal"){
            cell.PostsRareImageView.image = [imageFromAssets]
        }

        return cell
    }


}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    PostsName.text = getPostsFromDisk()[indexPath.row].name

    //thougt i could save the selecte array to feedWrapper but its not working like expected
    feedWrapper = getPostsFromDisk()[indexPath.row].Rarity


}
```

I think my `var feedWrapper` isn't filled up at the beginning but I'm not sure how to do this

I hope someone can help me with this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload the **collectionView**. You can use this code:

Declare your variable with **didset** (Assumed that your array is inside view controller)

```
    var feedWrapper:[PostType] = [] {
    didSet {
         self.yourCollectionView.reloadData()
     }
    }
```